# iOS iPhone Simulator 5.0 EKAlarm not working

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm working on a calendar app and when I add an alarm ( EKAlarm) to my EKEvent using either an absolute date or a relative offset the alarm/reminder doesn't fire on the simulator. Am I missing something, is it suppose to work on the simulator? I searched and did not find anything that says anything to the contrary. I am able to create UILocalNotifications and that works fine, I get the alerts/notifications for that in the simulator.

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no calendar app in the simulator so it won't work as expected. You will need to test on an actual device.

Comment: I didn't even think about that! I guess I should be using UILocalNotifications instead of EKAlarms because I want my app to open when the alert/reminder comes up and not the iPhone calendar app. Thanks!